# MySQL Workbench: Do not open new tab on "Select Rows"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

If you right click on a table in MySQL Workbench and click "Select Rows - Limit 1000" a new tab will be created. In the old version this new query would simple override your current tab.

This new setup often means I quickly get hundreds of tabs open in MySQL Workbench and I lose important ones. Its a bit of a mess for someone like me who uses that feature a lot.

Anyway to get the old functionality back?

Comment: You probably don't have that many tables that you have to run a select everytime you look at one. So I assume you want to re-run a select several times on a number your tables. Why not simply do a refresh once you have opened a tab for a table, instead?

Comment: I do that sometimes. But I find it takes more work to manage everything. It gets messy and is slowing down my programming. Its like each new version of workbench adds a new nice feature but also adds something else to reduce my productivity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution... when you right click on the table.. don't select "Select Rows - Limit 1000"... the option two below that will put the query in your current tab..

[image: rightclick on table name]

the option "Send to SQL Editor" is what you want to put it in the current query tab

**do this selection:**

[image]

Comment: That wont exactly work, as it would take more clicks, and I would then still need to click execute. My goal here is to reduce the clutter and the clicks by having the same functionality as the old version of mySQL.

Comment: @Chris6657456456 this will work as its one more click... and it doesn't require you to execute it.. it will execute by itself..

Comment: No luck, I even just updated to the latest MySQL. When I do that is only injects the select all query to the query window (so if there is junk in it already it will still be there)